# Is there a SFINAE test to check if an enum is unsigned?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Actually, I'm not sure if using the `operator<` or any other comparison operator other than `operator==` is even valid, but I've not seen anything to suggest otherwise.  So assuming that is valid, is there a way of determining if an enum is valid using SFINAE?

Comment: Are you trying to see if any valid value for an enum type is negative, or if a specific value is positive?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but `std::is_signed<std::underlying_type<EnumType>::type>::value` might be what you're after.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for.  I want to do a single test to see if a value is less than it's max and not have to do another test to see if it is greater or equal to 0.  Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @user2093113: Oh, wait, is there someway of doing this with MSVS 2010 SP1?

Comment: what do you mean with "determining if an enum is valid"?

Comment: In particular, with `enum { read=1, write=2 }` the value 3 (`read | write` is in range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While

```
std::is_signed<std::underlying_type<EnumType>::type>::value
```

is the portable solution, however it is not yet available in all commonly used compilers. From the question it's not clear whether you are also asking about `enum class`, or just about `enum`, but maybe this work-around will do the job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

enum S : int {};
enum U : unsigned {};
enum class SC : int {};
enum class UC : unsigned {};

template< typename E >
struct is_enum_signed {
    static const bool value = E(-1) < E(0);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << is_enum_signed<S>::value << std::endl
              << is_enum_signed<U>::value << std::endl
              << is_enum_signed<SC>::value << std::endl
              << is_enum_signed<UC>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't checked whether or not it is standard-conforming, I'm just trying to offer an alternative of which you need to verify applicability and correctness for your environment...

Comment: Actually, I implemented my solution in a similar way last night.